# Launch an exe by a web service ASP.NET framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have to create a web service that must use a desktop application (Autodesk Inventor).
The problem is that the web service is working under IIS and it not allow to start a desktop application, I get error, I read that this is because IIS is a service and cannot use/launch a GUI application.
My problem is that to automatize the task I MUST use Inventor.
I tried to create a windows service, web app but I get the same error.

If is not possible for me is also good to create a stand alone application on the server but the problem is the comunication between client and server, I prefer to use technologies like web api because all is ready, I wrote a code using UPD to comunicate but it is hard to manage.

Someone know how to solve this problem?

P.s. I tried to run the code by cmd using dotnet but it doesn't start, if it start I can solve the problem.

Thanks a lot for any suggestion.

Valerio Pittavino